# How to convert duplicate numbers into corresponding number-letter pairs?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of numbers that define steps. I want to convert it into a human-readable format so that only the duplicate steps get "numbered" by letters.

Here is an example:

```
0 => 'Step 1A'
0 => 'Step 1B'
0 => 'Step 1C'
1 => 'Step 2'
2 => 'Step 3A'
2 => 'Step 3B'
3 => 'Step 4'
```

Here is what I've tried:

```js
let steps = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
let stepCount = new Map()

steps = steps.map(step => {
  stepCount[step] = stepCount[step] + 1 || 0
  return 'Step ' + (step+1) + String.fromCharCode(65 + stepCount[step])
})

console.log(steps)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object for keeping track of the step.

For getting a letter, you could use `toString` with base 36.

```js
let steps = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
    stepCount = {};

steps = steps.map((step, i, a) => {
    if (step !== a[i - 1] && step !== a[i + 1]) return 'Step ' + (step + 1);
    stepCount[step] = stepCount[step] || 0;
    return 'Step ' + (step + 1) + (stepCount[step]++ + 10).toString(36).toUpperCase();
});

console.log(steps);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array.reduce`, you can get the count of duplicated items and based on that data, can get the result as follows.

```js
let steps = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
const groupBy = steps.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur] ? acc[cur] ++ : acc[cur] = 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

const output = Object.entries(groupBy).flatMap(([ step, count ]) => {
  return count === 1 ? `Step ${+step + 1}` : Array.from({length: count}, (_, i) => i).map((index) => `Step ${+step + 1}${String.fromCharCode(65 + index)}`);
});
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```